# A question about tensor product and multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a commutative ring, $A$ be an algebra over $k$. The tensor product $A\otimes A$ is over $k$. If $\sum_{i} a_i \otimes b_i=\sum_j c_j\otimes d_j$, where $a_i,b_i,c_j,d_j\in A$, I wonder if $\sum_i a_i b_i=\sum_j c_j d_j$? Or if that holds under some conditions?

Thank you!

Comment: This is false in general. Consider the point $(2,2)$ which can be written as the sum $(1,1) + (1,1)$. LHS is 4 and RHS is 2

Comment: @ amcalde Ok,thank you.

Comment: @amcalde I suppose $(2,2)$ stands for $2\otimes2$ which equals $4(1\otimes 1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This works only for commutative $k$-algebras.)

**Hint.** One can define a ring homomorphism $A\otimes_kA\to A$ by $\sum a_i\otimes b_i\mapsto\sum a_ib_i$.

Comment: Is that ok?  How to explain the example listed by amcalde?

Comment: @Penson I've thought I was clear in my comment under the question: his example is wrong! $2\otimes 2=1\otimes 1+1\otimes 1+1\otimes 1+1\otimes 1$, so we get $2\cdot 2=1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1$.

Comment: Yes , I got it wrong. Could you show me this ring homomorphism is well-defined?

Comment: @Penson The tensor product of algebras has a universal property; for more details see [here](https://drexel28.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/tensor-product-of-algebras/). Using this one can find immediately that ring homomorphism.